# About Process Of Char type of Oracel in PonyORM

Tags: python, sql, oracle, char, ponyorm

I used the PonyORM with Oracle, I found that it can not support the CHAR type of ORACLE well.

for example, I have a field whose type is CHAR(15), and I fill it up with 1234567890 after it is saved into this field, the oracle will add padding space after the value. like '1234567890     '.

If I use other tools to search with this field as the condition, there is no need to add padding space after the value, but PonyORM can not.
for example:

```
select * from table where field='1234567890     '; => the record can be retrieved

select * from table where field='1234567890';      => the record can not be retrieved.
```

Is there any method that solves this issue? Or, Maybe I need something extra set with PonyORM?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Oracle Select statement then you could use TRIM() function to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```sql
select * from table where TRIM(field) = '1234567890';
```

There are also LTRIM() and RTRIM() functions removing leading and trailing spaces respectively...
Oracle uses VARCHAR2 datatype for variable length string values.
Here is a small sample comparing CHAR and VARCHAR2 columns in Oracle:

```sql
Create table TEST_TABLE (CHAR_COL CHAR(10), VCHAR_COL VARCHAR2(10));
Insert Into TEST_TABLE VALUES('ABCD', 'EFGH');
Commit;
/*
Table TEST_TABLE created.
1 row inserted.
Commit complete.        */
Select  CHAR_COL, Length(CHAR_COL) "CHAR_LEN", 
        VCHAR_COL, Length(VCHAR_COL) "VCHAR_LEN"
From    TEST_TABLE
/*
CHAR_COL     CHAR_LEN VCHAR_COL   VCHAR_LEN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
ABCD               10 EFGH                4   */
```

Both columns created with space for 10 characters, both populated with 4 letters but the length of CHAR column is 10 while VARCHAR2 is 4.

Comment: In Oracle, if the column type is CHAR, even if the length of the value isn't up to the max length of the column, it can still be retrieved as well. no need to add trim on the column, which could make the index on this column invalid.

Comment: @user571102 That is true, but here is the problem with where condition not with retrival...

Comment: If you use the following SQL, it can be retrieved. select * from test_table where char_col='ABCD';

Comment: @user571102 Yes, I can get it too, but OP is telling us that he can not and we don't know what tool he uses and how.

Comment: you can ark him.  In general, all of the tools can archive this task. maybe the column type   they used is VARCHAR, not CHAR.

Comment: Let back to my question. I think it is caused by the PonyORM. I tried the cx_oracle directly, which is a db provider in PonyORM, the result is OK. but PonyORM can not.

Answer (score 0):

No choice, I wrote a help function to add the padding space and called it when the column type in Oracle is CHAR, which is defined with sql_type parameter in the Optional or Required constructor in PonyORM

```
def wrapChar(field: Optional, value:str):
if field.sql_type and field.sql_type.upper().startswith('CHAR'):
    value = value.strip().ljust(field.args[0], ' ')
```

here is an example of usage.

```
frootitemno = wrapChar(CUSTOMSTRMH.frootitemno, frootitemno)
```